# Integral transformation

Tags: calculus, integration, transformation

I'm trying to do a transformation of an integration, I have that $$\int_{0.5}^1\int_0^{0.5}e^{xy}xydxdy$$

And I want to get that integrate
$$\int_0^1\int_0^1 f(x,y)dxdy$$
Where the value of the second integral has the same value as the first, or something quite close

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take $u = 2x$ and $v = 2y-1$

Comment: When $x=0,u=0$ and $x=0.5,u=0.25$

Comment: Oh you're right, fixed

Comment: You can write the integrate with this transformation, they are equivalent right?

Comment: Just for readers, they would be equivalent if the Jacobian was non-zero; the direct analogy is being able to invert a matrix giving new coordinates in terms of old.